# What is "sc(41)"?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I just downloaded windows terminal and looking at the shortcut keys it has the following:

[image]

How do I type `sc(41)` on the keyboard?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>

> The "Quake Mode" key binding has been changed from windows+backtick to
> windows+sc(41), which is "the key where backtick is on the US-104
> keyboard"

https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/releases/tag/v1.11.2421.0

> Programmers use the grave accent symbol as a separate character (i.e.,
> not combined with any letter) for a number of tasks. In this role, it
> is known as a backquote, or backtick.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent

Comment: The first link was helpful, so now I see `sc` stands for `scancode` I believe.

Comment: I particularly liked "Use vk(xxx) or sc(xxx) to (in the darkness) bind these keys. The Settings UI will also produce them from time to time.". I have to assume that since MS has no sense of humor that they are aware of, that parenthetical reference will disappear over time.

Comment: @JesseGood Yeah. each key is assigned a scan code (a device-dependent identifier for the key on the keyboard), and the keyboard device driver interprets a scan code and translates (maps) it to a virtual-key code. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-keyboard-input

Comment: Yeah, on my keyboard sc41 seems to be a colon, so that is why they stopped using `backtick` and changed to `sc(41)`

Answer (score 3):

Just for AutoHotkey user.

Use `Send, #{sc29}` to mock that. (note that `{scXXX}` is in hex, and hex(41)=29